How to use grep to check if a pattern line exists and write to another file?
I have log file with contents as like this
The color is Orange then can used to binding.
The color is Black then can used to binding.
The animal Lion need to carefully. 
The color is Black then can used to binding.
The animal Zebra need to carefully. 
The animal Tiger need to carefully.
The animal Bee need to skip.
The color is White then can used to binding.
The color is Yellow then can used to binding.
The animal Ant need to skip.
The animal Tiger need to carefully. 
The color is Red then can used to filled.
The color is Green then can used to filled.

I want to check if line contains pattern and not exists then write to another log.
#!/bin/bash
source_file="/home/user1/source/source_sample.log"
dest_file="/home/user1/dest/dest_sample.log

#define line with pattern
pattern1=".*then can used to binding"
pattern2=".*need to carefully"

#check if line of pattern exist or not in destination file, if not then write it
grep -e "$pattern1" -e "$pattern2" $source_file >> $dest_file

The expected output on dest_sample.log would be like this. If the line of pattern does not exist in destination file, then write it. If already have exist , dont write it.
The color is Orange then can used to binding.
The color is Black then can used to binding.
The animal Lion need to carefully. 
The animal Zebra need to carefully. 
The animal Tiger need to carefully.
The color is White then can used to binding.
The color is Yellow then can used to binding.


If you don't care about order you can just paste all the matching lines including duplicates then sort | uniq the destination file

my log file more than a thousand lines, pls look at my expected result. If line have a pattern and never exists in destination file.

Sorting a thousand lines is no big deal. Unless you tell us that the order matters, my solution answers your requirements.

the order/sequence not impact , the requirement just line contains the pattern and not exist in destination log file. If destination log file already have, dont write that line. Look at the result 7 lines from 13 lines

While I did not downvote, please see https://idownvotedbecau.se/unclearquestion - try Grammarly or ChatGPT to get a clearer version of what you are trying to ask. A better written question will get you quicker, better answers. Good luck!

I think the language barrier is causing some trouble here.
Apologies if I miss what you want.
First, there are some lines in your data which look identical, but aren't; some have spaces at the end while others do not.
I removed the spaces before processing. If they matter, just leave them. Other answers here have examples of removing them in-process, though I could add that logic if you like.
What you asked was a way to do this with grep:
grep -Fxvf $dest_file $source_file | # Fixed string search 
  grep -E 'then can used to binding|need to carefully' >> $dest_file

It requires two passes.
First, a -Fixed-string -x(exact match) -v(exclusion) scan of $source_file using the lines of $dest_file as a -file of match strings. This gives us only lines from $source_file NOT in $dest_file already.
Pipe this to grep -E 'then can used to binding|need to carefully' (or grep -e "$pattern1" -e "$pattern2") to select lines you want from the output of the first grep and append to $dest_file.
If it is possible there can be duplicate new lines in $source_file, you may want to eliminate the dups before adding them to $dest_file:
grep -Fxvf $dest_file $source_file | # Fixed string search 
  grep -E 'then can used to binding|need to carefully' |
  sort -u >> $dest_file

This will alter your ordering unless $source_file has order you can reproduce, but you said order doesn't matter.
A Better Way
What you asked was a way to use grep, but awk can do this in one process, one pass (each file), without reordering your data.
awk 'NR==FNR{seen[$0]=1;next} 1==seen[$0]{next} 
  /then can used to binding|need to carefully/{seen[$0]=1;print}
' $dest_file $source_file >> $dest_file


awk to the rescue!
$ awk '/then can used to binding|need to carefully/ && ($1=$1) && !a[$0]++' file

The color is Orange then can used to binding.
The color is Black then can used to binding.
The animal Lion need to carefully.
The animal Zebra need to carefully.
The animal Tiger need to carefully.
The color is White then can used to binding.
The color is Yellow then can used to binding.

filter only matching lines, normalize fields (get rid of extra spaces), and filter only the unique entries.

awk '!/re/{next} !seen[$0]++ && NR>FNR' old input >new ?

If log files won't fit in memory, you care about line order, and you don't care about trailing whitespace:
(
    awk '
        /then can be used to binding|need to carefully/ { 
            sub(/[[:space:]]+$/,"")
            print NR FS $0
        }
    ' source.log | sort -k2 -u ;

    awk '
        /then can be used to binding|need to carefully/ { 
            sub(/[[:space:]]+$/,"")
            print NR FS $0 RS NR FS $0
        }
    ' destination.log
) |
sort -k2 |
uniq -f1 -u |
sort -n |
sed 's/^[0-9]* //' > new.log

cat new.log >> destination.log


first awk finds lines in source that match the regex, trims trailing whitespace, and prints prefixed by line number; its output is then de-duplicated using sort, ignoring the line numbers (field 1)
second awk repeats the filtering for the destination but prints each line twice
output from both awks is combined and re-sorted
then uniq discards duplicates, also ignoring line numbers

since every line that is in the destination appears at least twice, all lines already in destination are discarded


the third sort restores results to original file order
then sed deletes the line number
finally, any new results are appended to the destination



If log files are small, @karafka's approach can be modified:
awk '
    !/then can be used to binding|need to carefully/ { next }
    { sub(/[[:space:]]+$/,"") }
    !seen[$0]++ && NR>FNR
' destination.log source.log >new.log

cat new.log >>destination.log


filter out lines that don't match regex

trim trailing whitespace

store that line has been seen

the first time a line is seen, if it came from new input, then print it

append new results to destination



A simple egrep command will do the filtering, sort -u can be used to eliminate duplicates in the output.
$ egrep '(then can used to binding|need to carefully)' input.txt | sort -u
The animal Lion need to carefully.
The animal Tiger need to carefully.
The animal Tiger need to carefully.
The animal Zebra need to carefully.
The color is Black then can used to binding.
The color is Orange then can used to binding.
The color is White then can used to binding.
The color is Yellow then can used to binding.


Line The animal Tiger need to carefully. have exists, dont write it more time. pls look the sample file and compare with my expected result .

@BrianCrist that's because the lines are different: one has a trailing space

@jhnc , how about if i run script more time, the result need only 7 lines from 13 lines

@BrianCrist yes, most answers didn't notice that requirement
